# How can I unit test a custom element

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-component, jestjs, custom-element

I have a class that extends `HTMLElement`.  From reading this thread

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/574#issuecomment-231683089

I see that I can't instantiate a custom element with out getting a `Illegal constructor`.  Additionally, the `registerElement` looked promising as it returned the constructor for the custom element but that is now deprecated for using `CustomElementRegistry.define()` that 1. exists on the window object and 2. returns void.  Any solutions will be greatly appreciated thank you.

for this particular setup I am attempting to use native custom elements as opposed to a web component framework because I only need custom elements.  Also, I am using TypeScript and attempting to use Jest to test it.

Comment: You must use something like Karma or Web Component Tester or something else that uses a browser for the tests.  Then your component can be instantiated in the browser and tested.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what extactly your element is doing you could consider to take the design principles "separation of concern" and "inversion of control" into account.

Separation of concern would be achieved when different things are implemented in different classes. This would also mean that the separated things can be tested without instantiating a concrete HtmlElement.

Inversion of controll comes in handy at this Point because if the dependencies of the separated classes (probably the HtmlElement) are settable from outside of the class, you can easily stub or mock the HtmlElement by giving a stub to the test-instance.

The idea is to design your code in a way that it is independent of things that are not accessible or controllable in unittests.